# What's the difference between C++, C++/CX, and C++/WinRT?

Tags: c++

I'm getting started with C++ in Visual Studio 2019 for reference.

Are any of them more useful for certain application types? (eg. game vs spreadsheet)
Are any of them more useful for certain platforms? (eg. console vs desktop)

What I've found so far is, They are component extensions.
Is this relevant if I'm writing my own extensions, or are these core extensions?

reference links are welcome

I apologize if this is a dumb question.

Comment: Follow the white rabbit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B/WinRT. It's not really a dumb question, but it is a question that can easily be answered by reading common resources like wikipedia. In a nutshell: C++ a programming language, C++/CX is an extension to the C++ language that used to facilitate developing winrt/uwp apps. C++/winrt is the next generation approach for such apps, instead of an extension to C++, it's simply an API based on regular C++.

Comment: The reference docs at [C++/CX Language Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/visual-c-language-reference-c-cx?view=msvc-160) and [Move to C++/WinRT from C++/CX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/move-to-winrt-from-cx) cover some grounds and have useful links.

Comment: there's also C++/CLI which is a language for targeting CLI ( the runtime .NET framework runs on)

Answer (score 2):

yms's comment deserves to be an answer, so here it is:

> In a nutshell:
>
> - C++ a programming language,
> - C++/CX is an extension to the C++ language that used to facilitate developing winrt/uwp apps.
> - C++/winrt is the next generation approach for such apps, instead of an extension to C++, it's simply an API based on regular C++.